# Python socket test recv() data

Tags: python, sockets

I have a problem with my python script using socket. I want to test if the client use the correct file, not an other tool like telnet. The server :

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data == 'test':
        print 'ok'
    else:
        print '!'
        conn.close()
```

The client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(HOST, PORT)
s.send('test')
```

The client send 'test' to the server to verify that it's the correct file.
But in the case where the client send nothing (if the client uses another way to connect), i can't test if conn.recv(1024) equals to 'test' because the script freezes, i need to wait the client stop and the server unfreezes.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` function to limit the time your server waits for new client connection or incoming data from client:

```
import socket
import select
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while 1:

    # wait up to 60 seconds that a client connects
    newClient,_,_ = select.select([s], [], [], 60)

    if not (newClient):
        # no client wanted to connect  
        print 'No new client in last 60 seconds!'
        return
    else:
        # new connection 
        print 'New client!'        
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        # wait up to 60 seconds that the client send data
        readable,_,_ = select.select([conn], [], [], 60)
        if (readable):
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data == 'test':
                print 'ok'
            else:
                print 'client do not send test'
        else:
            print 'client send nothing'

        # close connection
        conn.close()
```

see [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html).